# How can 2 different left side navigation drawers be implemented in the same android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want to implement login in my android app. I want to show a different navigation drawer for logged in users and a different one for logged out users. Is it possible to hide the various sections inside the navigation drawer based on whether the user is logged in or not? Or can 2 different navigation drawers be implemented in the same app? What is the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be if you change 2 (included) layout's visibility on the Navigation Drawer's fragment. You can set a listener on the navigation drawer to listen for opens. Or Implement some kind of onUserSignedIn/Out listener on the Navigation Drawer's fragment, and there inflate different views, or here too you can set visibility on parts of the layout. I'm not sure what would be best practice, but this should work.